# adding popup on features in leaflet geojson-vt

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I have a map where i used the leafet-geojson-vt plugin (https://github.com/brandonxiang/leaflet-geojson-vt/tree/leaflet1.0.0) to draw GEOJSON data in a **canvas** layer with geojson-vt.

I'm able to add the layer to the map, however, I don't know how to add popups on click for each polygon/tile/feature in the layer. I've tried searching for examples but cannot find ones using the geojson-vt plugin.

How can I add such functionality using the example in the link above?

Any help is appreciated.